# Javascript stops running when referencing an empty field in a lookup relationship

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a lightning component where I'm trying to display a field that is in a lookup relationship. Sometimes the fields are empty. Here is my code which is self explanatory. **When the Initiative/FOA (lookup) field is empty. The 6 and 7 lines don't display.** This all occurs within a Callback.

```
var detail = response.getReturnValue();
console.log("1" + detail.Id);
cmp.set("v.oppdetails.Id", detail.Id);
console.log("2" +detail.FY__c);
cmp.set("v.oppdetails.FY__c", detail.FY__c );   
console.log("3" +detail.Active__c);                                                    
cmp.set("v.oppdetails.Active__c", detail.Active__c );
console.log("4" +detail.Abs__c);      
cmp.set("v.oppdetails.Abs__c", detail.Abs__c );  
console.log("5" +detail.Actv__c);  
cmp.set("v.oppdetails.Actv__c", detail.Actv__c );
console.log("6" +detail.Initiative_FOA__r.Name);
cmp.set("v.oppdetails.Initiative_FOA__r.Name", detail.Initiative_FOA__r.Name);
console.log("7" +detail.Project__r.Name);
cmp.set("v.oppdetails.Project__r.Name", detail.Project__r.Name );
```

Comment: Seems silly but did you check the query for the __r relationship ? Does you user that executes the code have access to the object and its relationship ? Check profiles / field level security

Comment: The query has that same __r relationship. I'm running this as a System Admin as well. If I have a Project, but not a Initiative, then the Project will not show.  If I have a Initiative and Project, both will show.

Comment: Both won't show if you don't have an iniative. Javascript is very permissive as you can compile code easily. What happens here is that if there is no iniative, the code will throw an error and not go further. Hence the last line not showing up

Comment: The error being a null pointer reference I guess

Comment: I figured as much. I was wondering if there was any around it.

Comment: Well, either you make sure the objet has always an object linked to it, either (and that's better), you test is there is a relationship in the first place. With a test like this : 
if (null != detail.Initiative_FOA__r.Name) {
cmp.set("v.oppdetails.Initiative_FOA__r.Name", detail.Initiative_FOA__r.Name);
}